# PCI DDS SAC D for small business with one emploee

Tags: pci-dss

I'm trying to figure out how to properly fill in PCI SAC D compliance form for a startup business with the only one owner/architect/developer/admin/QA/etc - all of them is me alone.

It's a web app for selling a particular intangible service. No card information is going to be stored. The reason for SAC D - I'd prefer to do some validation logic on my server side and have a total review and confirmation page that match the rest of UI.

Hosting environment will be AWS Beanstalk + RDS.

When I read it, common sense tells me to ignore statements like "Interview personnel" or "Review policies & procedures", but I expect that large corporate minds are not usually driven by common sense but by rules.

- I can hardly imaging formal process of interviewing myself and documenting what I've asked and what I've said, especially the benefits of doing that.
- Most of the questions in Requirement 8 make no sense either.
- Questions that assume that stuff is more then one employee make no sense.

Can those be skipped (N/A-ed) or should I formally do the exercise and generate some funny nonsense?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can N/A those questions.

Remember the SAQ is a *SELF* Assessment Questionnaire, not a test you are taking. The payment card industry is more concerned about your adherence to the "spirit" of PCI-DSS rather than hard fast rules. It's more about protecting cardholder data than it is complying with things that don't apply to your case. (Although anything that *does* apply should definitely be followed as a hard rule.)

If you did get audited, it would probably only be because you had a breach, which obviously would NOT be because you didn't "interview yourself" and put on a security ID badge when you sat down in front of your development computer :-D and I don't think you'd have any trouble at all getting that point across to the QSA.

Now, having all your security policies and procedures, network diagrams, firewall, etc. documented and reviewed periodically **does** apply, since for security guidelines to be followed on a continual basis, they must be reviewed on a continual basis. For these, just use common sense. In other words, go over your firewall rules and such at least as often as PCI-DSS requires and ask yourself, "Do I still need this ALLOW SNMP port 161 rule to be in effect?" etc. etc...*Oh dear I think I just told you to interview yourself...* :-D

Anyway, you get the idea.

Answer (score 0):

Are you really really sure you need SAQ D? It's a pretty big undertaking if you're starting from scratch. Is the money flowing into your merchant account? If so you could potentially get away with SAQ A which is going to make your life WAY easier. If not, then you're probably SAQ D service provider and you'll have no choice but to do SAQ D. In terms of styling and validation you could use an iFrame solution like [Braintree](https://www.braintreepayments.com/blog/your-checkout-our-iframes/), you have quite a lot of control and it reduces your PCI scope significantly.

In my experience talking with the bank that holds the merchant account is a good place to start, they're keen for secure systems to be developed, so are likely to give you advice on what you need to do. You could also engage a QSA but they are not cheap in general.

I don't think (though i'm not 100% sure) interviewing yourself is required, those instructions are for auditors to use to ensure that policy and procedures are being followed. For lone developers, a big problem is code reviews, you will need someone else to do that.

Comment: He definitely needs SAQ-D, as it is required when the payment page is served from the merchant server and when the merchant uses a custom or in-house developed checkout system.

Comment: I suggested he use an iFrame from a PCI level 1 provider, in that case he should be able to use SAQ A if he's the merchant. Or SAQ-EP if doing a direct post.